# Drupal Database or MySQL Databse

Tags: database

I want to create a dynamic website. 
Where does Drupal store its data?
Is a MySQL database required to store the data?
If Drupal has its own database, does it have any limitation? I am pretty new to Drupal.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As of Drupal 7, MySQL, PostgreSQL, and SQLite data types are supported in Drupal core.

Any web hosting company will offer at least one database server.

Basically:

1. you will copy the drupal files to your server via an FTP client
2. you will create a database from your web hosting company admin panel
3. you will go to www.yourwebsite.com/install.php and while installing Drupal you will provide the database credentials
4. done

You can find more info about creating your database here:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/installing-drupal-7/step-2-create-the-database